# jQuery ui autocomplete: Store the local data in a remote place without using a database?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm currently using a **local data** set for a jQuery ui autocomplete widget. Is there a way I could store this multidimensional array (data set) somewhere **remote** *without using a sql database*?

If I stored the array in a **php**, which would `echo` the whole array to the jQuery autocomplete function each call, would that be a safe way around it?  eg

```
<?php
echo json_encode( 
    array( array( label => "jQuery", 
                      desc => "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
                      other => "9834275 9847598023 753425828975340 82974598823" 
                    ),
               array( label => "jQuery UI", 
                      desc => "the official user interface library for jQuery",
                      other => "98 83475 9358 949078 8 40287089754 345 2345",
                    ),
               array( label => "Sizzle JS", 
                      desc => "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
                      other => "49857 2389442 573489057 89024375 928037890" 
                    )
             );
);
?>
```

Or if the whole array is `echo`'d that pretty much is like having a local data set which anyone could access (if they tried)?

http://jsfiddle.net/FUZPN/ (this is the simple functionality I have now with a local data set)

My array currently looks like so:

```
var projects = [
    {
        value: "jquery",
        label: "jQuery",
        desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
        other: "9834275 9847598023 753425828975340 82974598823"
    },
    {
        value: "jquery-ui",
        label: "jQuery UI",
        desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
        other: "98 83475 9358 949078 8 40287089754 345 2345"
    },
    {
        value: "sizzlejs",
        label: "Sizzle JS",
        desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
        other: "49857 2389442 573489057 89024375 928037890"
    }
];
```

Generally, is there a way to store an array remotely as safe as it would be using the `autcomplete -> php -> sql database` method?

Comment: I think you could just store the data in a plain text file and make an AJAX call to retrieve the contents of that file.

Comment: Also, why use a remote source at all? Why not just use a local source?

Comment: I'm trying to use the autocomplete widget for a dictionary type project. Giving users access to the whole list of words/definitions could lead to copycats, etc., I'm guessing if the list of words is stored somewhere remote, this would slow down users from obtaining the whole list (by going through each list using the autocomplete), but still allow others to use the functionality of the project. [I understand that there is not *ideal* way to keep data safe]

Comment: Yep, if someone wants your data all they'll have to do is look at the NET requests going out of their machine. If they're savvy enough to do "view source" then they're probably savvy enough to check out the response of the AJAX request you're making for data.